# How to list function calls

Tags: linux-kernel

How can I list all the calls to a particular function in the kernel (linux)? For instance, if I'm trying to audit some kernel code and I want to know all the places where there's a call to copy_from_user(), how do I list them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a web service that does this exact thing for you: [the Elixir Cross Referencer.](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source)

[For example, here are the results for `copy_from_user`.](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/copy_from_user)

If you need the tool for your own use, [the source code is available on Github.](https://github.com/bootlin/elixir)

Comment: Also, `ctags` is useful, and there might already be a `tags` target in the Makefile (if it follows any sort of standard target naming scheme).